# How to share common functions across multiple components

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I`m working on rebuilding an AngularJS application I built to the new Angular 5 framework. Ill admit I not not too familiar with Typescript and learning as I go.

I am trying to re-create an equivilent of a service in AngularJS. I have many common functions that need me to accessed via multiple components. So trough the Angular CLI I used the following command: `ng generate service Common`. I then added a testfunction and tried to inject the service into my componenent and tried to call it. I get an error saying it cannot find name ServiceTest.

Common.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class CommonService {

  public ServiceTest(data) {
    console.log(data)
  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

I then create a component that looks like so:

Share-Buttons.Components.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from '../../common.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-shared-buttons',
  templateUrl: './shared-buttons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shared-buttons.component.css']
})
export class SharedButtonsComponent implements OnInit {

  public params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  public invokeServiceTest() {
    ServiceTest(this.params.data);
  }

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```

In my aoo.modules the service is in my providers like so:

```
  providers: [CommonService],
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: The problem is you didn't inject the service into the component via the constructor.

Comment: `constructor(private commonService: CommonService) { this.commonService.ServiceTest("something")}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you need to do in the component in order to consume the service:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonService } from '../../common.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-shared-buttons',
  templateUrl: './shared-buttons.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shared-buttons.component.css']
})
export class SharedButtonsComponent implements OnInit {

  public params: any;

  agInit(params: any): void {
    this.params = params;
  }

  public invokeServiceTest() {
    this.commonService.ServiceTest(this.params.data);
  }

  constructor(private commonService: CommonService) { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

As you can see, the service is being inject via the constructor. Then, in the `invokeServiceTest`, the service function is called.

Injecting a service using the constructor with the `private` (or `public` for that matter) keyword creates a local variable for the service. You can then access all public functions and properties in a service via the `this.serviceName`, `this.commonService` in this case.

Comment: It seems to work but im getting weird errors 

`ERROR Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[SharedButtonsComponent -> CommonService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[SharedButtonsComponent -> CommonService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CommonService!`

Does this mean anything to you?

Comment: Usually, that means that you are missing the `CommonService` being listed in the providers array in the app.module.ts. But, according to your post, you have that. Did you remove it for some reason?

Comment: Where is your `SharedButtonsComponent` included at?

Comment: Managed to fix it by updating my angular CLI version and running ng serve -–preserve-symlinks. Not quite sure what happened but seems okay now.